# Histograma en python no me muestra todas las columnas

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Tengo un dos *dataframe*, uno por cada año y cada uno tiene la información de meses del 1 al 12. El problema radica es que al hacer la gráfica **hist** se suma el mes 1 y 2 tambien los meses 11 y 12. No se como solucionar este error .

````
colors = ['#F7D358','#0B3861']
f , ax =plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(30,10))
anio2020.Mes.plot.hist(edgecolor='white',color='#F7D358',ax=ax[0],)
anio2021.Mes.plot.hist(edgecolor='white',color='#0B3861',ax=ax[1])
ax[0].set_title ('Empleabilidad en el año 2020',fontdict = font1)
ax[0].set_xlabel('Meses', fontdict = font2)
ax[0].set_ylabel('')
ax[0].grid(axis="y", color="black")
ax[1].set_title ('Empleabilidad en el año 2021',fontdict = font1)
ax[1].set_xlabel('Meses', fontdict = font2)
ax[1].grid(axis="y", color="black")
plt.show[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]```
````

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gráfica generada

Answer (score 0):

Sin saber qué tienes exactamente en los dataframes creo que el problema lo tienes a la hora de generar el histograma.

`.plot.hist()` utiliza por defecto 10 bandejas para el histograma, pero puedes modificarlo con el parámetro `bins=int`:

```
anio2020.Mes.plot.hist(edgecolor='white', color='#F7D358', ax=ax[0], bins=12)
anio2021.Mes.plot.hist(edgecolor='white', color='#0B3861', ax=ax[1], bins=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Como los meses son valores discretos, los *bins* tienen que estar alrededor de estos valores. Simplemente poniendo `bins=12` pondrá 13 divisiones entre el valor mínimo (`1`) y máximo (`12`). Es decir, a posiciones `[1, 1.917, 2.833, 3.75, 4.667, 5.583, 6.5, 7.417, 8.333, 9.25, 10.167, 11.083, 12]`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2022)
anio2020 = pd.DataFrame({'Mes': np.random.randint(1, 13, 200)})
anio2021 = pd.DataFrame({'Mes': np.random.randint(1, 13, 250)})

colors = ['#F7D358', '#0B3861']
f, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 4), sharey=True)
anio2021.Mes.plot.hist(edgecolor='white', color='#0B3861', ax=axs[1], bins=np.arange(0.5, 13))
for ax, df, año, color in zip(axs, [anio2020, anio2021], [2020, 2021], colors):
    df.Mes.plot.hist(edgecolor='white', color=color, ax=ax, bins=np.arange(0.5, 13))
    ax.set_title(f'Empleabilidad en el año {año}')
    ax.set_xlabel('Meses')
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    ax.grid(axis="y", color="black")
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))  # muestra cada mes
    ax.tick_params(labelleft=True)  # con "sharey=True" las etiquetas son invisible
    ax.margins(x=0.01)  # menos espacio blanco
    for lado in ['top', 'right']:
        ax.spines[lado].set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.hist con 12 meses]